# SBCL and custom-made repl

Tags: read-eval-print-loop, sbcl

I have built an executable with sbcl (save-lisp-and-die), which executes files and does things. I would like to add the possibility to the user to enter a REPL at some point of the program. The first thought was to start writing my own by adding functionality to (loop (print (eval (read)))). However, is there a way to use SBCL's loop instead?

Thank you in advance,
Dimitris

Comment: yes, you can just call `(loop (print (eval (read))))` as part of your saved core. What's the problem with that?